# NSProgressIndicator like in Finder or Mac App Store?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to adjust parameters of NSProgressIndicator so that it will look like the one from Finder or Mac App Store?

```
    [self.progressIndicator setControlSize:NSMiniControlSize];
```

Doesn't seem to have any effect, setting control size to small via IB works, but it still looks too big in comparison with Mac App Store indicator.

Comment: You mean the white progress bar that appears in Finder's list view during copies and in Launchpad during app installation?

Comment: Right, or another one which appears in App Store during app installation

Comment: It wouldn't exist if it were impossible, but probably is custom or part of a private Apple framework. If that's the case, it may yet become public in some future version. You should probably file a Radar asking for them to make it public and, in the meantime, write your own clone of it.